# Dropbox sync with one folder on Linux

Tags: debian, dropbox, symbolic-link

I have a folder on my Debian server at `/mnt/Pool/Photos` which I want to exactly sync with a folder in Dropbox at `/Photos`. This allows me to have my photos locally stored for easy access, but also backed up to the cloud. I don't want anything else from my Dropbox on the computer (ie selectively sync `/Photos` only)

The way I tried to do this was installing Dropbox on Debian, excluding everything from sync, making a symlink to `/mnt/Pool/Photos` in the `/Dropbox` folder and then selectively including `/Photos` to sync, however Dropbox now doesn't support symlinks. Dropbox ended up creating a second folder `Photos (Debian conflicted with at...)` and then started redownloading the whole folder instead of recognising it was already there.

How can I go about setting what I want up (a sync of just one folder with Dropbox that already exists)?

Comment: If you are willing to do without symlinks, better modify the post.

Comment: Hmm, don't think it says anywhere I have to use symlinks.

Comment: Have you tried the [Dropbox desktop app](https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/desktop/desktop-application-overview)? It has more capabilities for syncing folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use [bind mounts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount).**

This answer assumes that you have permissions to edit and reload `/etc/fstab`.

**Note:** Please take a backup of important data in a separate location before trying this.

---

**Step 1:** Stop Dropbox.

**Step 2:** Move existing contents of `[Dropbox]/Photos` to `/mnt/Pool/Photos`

**Step 3:** Add this to your `/etc/fstab` file:

```
/mnt/Pool/Photos   [Dropbox]/Photos   none   bind   0 0
```

(Replace `[Dropbox]` with your Dropbox sync root path.)

**Step 4:** Reboot system or `sudo mount -a` to reload all fstab entries.

**Step 5:** Start Dropbox.

---

Tested on Dropbox v85.4.155 (on Arch Linux).

Answer (score -1):

#### How can I go about setting what I want up?

You can't, at least not using `dropbox`:

> As of mid-2019, Dropbox no longer follows items outside of your Dropbox account that are linked to by a symlink.

Source [How to use symlinks with Dropbox | Dropbox Help](https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/sync-uploads/symlinks)

The feature was removed because it was broken:

> Issues occur with syncing when the files are located elsewhere and the
>   symlink is within the Dropbox folder instead. [This can cause
>   performance issues and high CPU usage when trying to sync the
>   files](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Files-folders/Best-practices-for-using-symlinks-symbolic-links/m-p/349299#M52908).
>
> In some cases, the desktop app may even just sync the symlink file
>   itself and not the referenced file.
>
> This will mean the actual file won’t be synced to your Dropbox account
>   so you wont be able to access the actual file via the web or other
>   devices your account syncs to.

Source [Solved: Re: Best practices for using symlinks (symbolic li... - Dropbox Community - 349296](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Files-folders/Best-practices-for-using-symlinks-symbolic-links/m-p/349299#M52908)

Comment: I don't necessarily have to use sym-links. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: @Sam. I don't use dropbox so no idea ...